# BCP neither gives results nor outputs anything when using valid statements but it does throw errors when passing invalid parameters

Tags: sql-server, linux, database, rhel, bcp

I have to use **bcp** command-line tool to export data from an *SQL Server* database to a file in a Red Hat server.
I am (apparently) using valid statements but **bcp** is not producing any kind of output/results.
However, when I execute statements with missing or invalid parameters it displays the respective error.
I am looking for the reason of this issue (e.g. defective installation, bad usage of **bcp**, lack of permissions or any other known conflict) and how to fix it.

---

**bcp statement:**

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S server -U user -P password
```

**bcp usage:**

```
usage: /opt/microsoft/bin/bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-t field terminator]     [-r row terminator]
  [-a packetsize]           [-K application intent]
  [-S server name or DSN if -D provided]             [-D treat -S as DSN]
  [-U username]             [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-d database name]
```

**bcp version:**

```
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 11.0.2270.0
```

**SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION`):**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
   May 14 2014 18:34:29
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
   Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

**Distribution:**

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (KornShell).
```

---

## Invalid statements with respective error message (examples).

```
bcp THAT_TUB_ACE.oh_nerd.table_name out ./data.txt -c -S sr._bear -U you_sr. -P pass_sword

    SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
    SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 11001
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
    SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 11001
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9
```

...

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name ./data.txt -c -S valid_server -U valid_user -P bad_word

    bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S valid_server -U valid_user -P bad_word
    SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
    Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'valid_user'.
```

## SUMMARY.

The objective is to generate a datafile using the following syntax (or similar):

```
bcp fully_qualified_table_name out ./data.txt -c -S server -U user -P password
```

The facts are:

- When running a valid **bcp** statement there's nothing in the window at all (no output) and no datafile is created.
- I cannot use option `-T` (trusted connection using integrated security) for **bcp** so I have to specify the *server, user and password*.
- Tried `queryout` option on a very simple small table already but still no luck.
- Credentials are valid, I successfully tested them using `sqlcmd` like the following: `sqlcmd -S server -U user -P password -Q 'SELECT * FROM really_small_table'`.
- The **bcp** statements under *"Invalid statements with respective error message (examples)"* section of this question are just examples of invalid statements to show that **bcp** actually does something but giving the expected results.

Comment: Does  your user have write access to the folder you want to write the output file to? It's normal to get the errors for bad credentials as BCP tries to connect to the SQL server first, so if that fails it won't attempt to do anything else.

Comment: Hi @IonutTulai , permissions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you've already solved your problem, but I had a similar problem configuring PyODBC for Python 3.4 on RedHat 7.1.  I was trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2016.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

The real problem for me was ODBC/FreeTDS configuration.  Here are the installation steps I took and the eventual solution.

1. I started by installing [Microsoft's ODBC driver for redhat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).  This likely isn't required, but I list it here since I never removed it from my redhat machine for fear of breaking ODBC.
2. Install ODBC and ODBC development files: `yum install unixODBC-devel.x86_64`
3. Install FreeTDS: `yum install freetds.x86_64`
4. Update config files.  Steps 1-3 took about 10 minutes.  I spent a very frustrating day trying various configurations, and usually I was able to connect via `tsql` (FreeTDS debugging tool, more on that below), but never via Python.  I eventually stumbled upon [this blog](https://zend18.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/218197897-Configuring-a-Linux-Server-to-Connect-to-an-MSSQL-Database-Using-ODBC), which pointed me to the correct driver via `ldconfig -p | grep libtdsodbc` (I believe this points to the FreeTDS driver, hence why Microsoft's driver probably isn't needed).

The eventual configuration I ended up with is as follows:

**/etc/odbc.ini** (note: I had to create this file as the ODBC/FreeTDS installation process didn't create it for me.)

```
[SQLServer]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver      = SQLServer
Servername  = your_sql_hostname
TDS Version = 0.95
Database    = your_database_name (not to be confused with instance name)
Port        = 1433
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[ODBC]
# Enables ODBC debugging output.  Helpful to see where things stop working.
Trace = yes
TraceFile = /etc/odbcinst.trace

[SQLServer]
Description=TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver=/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Driver64=/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount=1
```

## Troubleshooting tips

**tsql** is debugging/testing tool that comes with FreeTDS.  It is your friend.  I was able to use it early on to verify that the networking side of things was correct (i.e. no firewalls blocking access, hostnames resolve, etc).

Use `tsql -H your_sql_hostname -L` to get the instance names and ports from your SQL server.  Note that you'll use port 1433 (which is the MS SQL instance discovery port) in your ODBC configuration above, not these port numbers.

```
ServerName   your_sql_hostname
InstanceName instance_1_name
IsClustered  No
Version      13.0.x.x
tcp          5555

ServerName   your_sql_hostname
InstanceName instance_2_name
IsClustered  No
Version      13.0.x.x
tcp          6666
```

Use the port from the previous tsql command like so:

`tsql -H your_sql_hostname -p your_sql_instance_port -D your_database_name -U your_username -P your_password`

You should get a prompt.  Try querying some data from your database (note that you have to type `GO` on a separate line to actually run your query).  If this works but you still can't connect via Python/other-app, it usually means ODBC/FreeTDS are installed correctly and there are no networking problems, but your ODBC configuration isn't correct.

```
1> SELECT TOP 1 * FROM your_table
2> GO
{a row will be returned here}
1>    # prompt returns, use `exit` to get out
```